# Application crashing when returning 1 row in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that is populated with an array called json. If the length of json is 0, I would like to return 1 row in my tableview.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  TableViewCell *cell = [self->tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
  NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  //content is the name of label in the custom cell
  if ([json count]>0) {
    cell.content.text = [info objectForKey:@"message_text"];
  }
  else
    cell.content.text = @"There are currently no messages. Please pull down to refresh";

  return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if([json count]>0)
    return [json count];
else
    return 1;

}
```

The above code causes my application to crash and I am unsure why. Why does this not work and how can I resolve the issue.
I get the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Comment: Please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: I added the cellForRowAtIndexPath method @Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code:

```
NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//content is the name of label in the custom cell
if ([json count]>0) {
  cell.content.text = [info objectForKey:@"message_text"];
}
else
   cell.content.text = @"There are currently no messages. Please pull down to refresh";
```

To:

```
//content is the name of label in the custom cell
if ([json count]>0) {
  NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.content.text = [info objectForKey:@"message_text"];
}
else
   cell.content.text = @"There are currently no messages. Please pull down to refresh";
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you so much. Just out of curiosity, why was the problem occurring and why does the code you provided work. I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: You get item outside of your checking code. When no item it out of range and it will crash.